# how to access variables getter and setter from another class

Tags: java

I have 3 classes

```
public class GameInfo 
{
  private  int num;
  public void setNum(int num){
         this.num=num;
    }
  public int getNum(){
         return num; 
   }
}

public class NewGame
{ 
  public void foo(){
    GameInfo g = new GameInfo();
    g.setNum(10);
}
}

public class StartGame()
{
   //i want to access the num in GameInfo being set by NewGame class. How to do that? 

}
```

if i create a new object of class GameInfo  in StartGame class like

```
GameInfo g = new GameInfo();
int number = g.getnum(); //it returns 0
```

i want to get 10 in number variable.

Comment: When do you think `g.setNum(10);` will be executed?

Comment: let me correct the code, it is in a method actually , which sets the value.

Comment: In `NewGame::foo()` (which we don't even know when or even *if* it is executed) you create a `GameInfo` object called `g`, then `g` is not used for anything. Then later on (or is it before? Who knows!) you create a new `GameInfo` object (if I understand correctly) and expect it to be the same as the one inside `foo()`?

Comment: I actually dont want to create a new object in StartGame class instead of it I want to get what I set in NewGame::foo(). Actually it is a large program, I cant post whole code here, I created an example to tell my problem. foo always get executed first and after that in StartGame class i want to access num

Comment: You'll have to save the `g` inside `foo()` somewhere, and then have a way of retrieving it. As it is now it just goes out of scope and dissappears.

Answer (score 0):

private member `num` of `GameInfo` is initalized wtih 0 per default. If you want to return something else you have to call `g.setNum(10)` before `g.getNum()`.

Answer (score -1):

Sine ***num*** variable is an instance member of the **GameInfo** class, So every time you create a new object of **GameInfo**, the value for ***num*** will be set to default i.e, **0** here.

So, in order to obtain **10** as return of ***getnum()*** method, you will need to first invoke the setter method as ***setnum(10)*** on the same object reference.

```
public class StartGame() {
    NewGame newGame = new NewGame();
    newGame.foo();  // It sets 10, but this value will only be accessible from your NewGame's instance.
    GameInfo info = new GameInfo();
    info.setnum(10);  // It sets num to 10
    int number = info.getnum(); //it returns 10
}
```